# Calculating a jackpot winner based on probabilities

Tags: algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms

Imagine a jackpot where users can bet as much as they want, and each bet increases their winning chance. Given a `roll [0-100]`, how would you calculate the winner?

**My solution and the pitfall**

To determine winning users, you could check if a drawn `roll [0-100]` falls between a stack of users' winning probabilities.

Winning probability for each user is calculated by applying `Fc(Bet, Pot Size) = Bet * 100 / Pot size`.

The only algorithm I have in mind to determine who the winner is, is to perform math server-side and iterate each user's winning probability, and check if `roll` falls within:

```
user_bets = [250,250,500]
pot_size = sum(user_bets)
roll = 32.21;
cur_range = [0,0]
for bet in user_bets:
    win_chance = bet * 100 / pot_size
    cur_range = [  cur_range[1] , win_chance + cur_range[1] ]
    if roll >= cur_range[0] and roll <= cur_range[1]:
        # cur_range[0] = 25, cur_range[1] = 50
        # We found the winner
        break
```

**Goal**

The goal is to possibly adopt a one-liner algorithm to determine the winner within `SQL` language, whereas **no iteration** is involved

**Graphic example**

```
User X = BET    =  $13.000
User Y = BET    =   $6.500
User Z = BET    =   $3.250

POT_SIZE        =  $22.750
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User X Win range               = 0 ->  57,14     (57% win chance)
User Y Win range               = 57.15 ->  85,71 (29% win chance)
User Z  Win range              = 85,72 ->  100   (14% win chance)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROLL Example          = 32.27...
WINNER                = User X
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROLL Example          = 91.38...
WINNER                = User Z
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus it's actually on the second line.

Comment: Your question already contains a complete solution.

Comment: ((Missed&found that.) The catch may be that there's a catch rather than a pitfall: the solution presented uses iteration, while one without is required.)

Comment: @greybeard is right. The pitfall is the iteration, for me.

Comment: @greybeard: the "no iteration" and "SQL" constraint make the question off-topic. Not counting total lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

For each user, sample the exponential distribution with rate equal to the size of that user's bet. The user with the smallest random variate wins the pot. Generation is something like $-\log(1 - \text{random}()) / \text{bet}$ where $\text{random}()$ returns a random number in $[0, 1)$.